# disabled firewall then apache stopped

Tags: iptables, apache-2.4

i was having some unrelated to the website server problems, so i stopped iptables. 
ever since then, apache wont serve pages. i only get the error This site can’t be reached. my.site.org took too long to respond. 
i tried reinstalling apache, disabling php, changing the owner/group of the www file, and a dozen other things. 
there is no server side error, and it appears apache is running, how can i get apache to serve pages again without restarting iptables as that breaks the rest of the server?

EDIT:

wouldnt let me copy the first two commands but it would the third:

[iptables -L -n](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oouDQ.png)

[iptables -t nat -L -n](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZRKC.png)

```
root@mineos ~# lsof -i
(LISTEN)
apache2     649          root    4u  IPv6   11604      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2    9079      www-data    4u  IPv6   11604      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2    9080      www-data    4u  IPv6   11604      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2    9081      www-data    4u  IPv6   11604      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2    9082      www-data    4u  IPv6   11604      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2    9083      www-data    4u  IPv6   11604      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```

i tried all these ports and got connection refused on all.

Comment: and yes i am aware running a server without a firewall is stupid and dangerous =P

Comment: Check apache logs. What does it say ?

Comment: How did you stop Iptables ? Whats the result of iptables -L ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you show us the iptables rules you had when apache was working?

```
$ iptables -L -n
and
$ iptables -t nat -L -n
```

Also check what address and port apache is listening on.

It's a wild guess, but there might be an iptables rule set up that forwards external requests to port 80 on your server to the port where apache is really listening.
Stopping iptables disables that rule and so your requests don't get answered.

**Edit:**

Apache is indeed listening on port 80, but...

I can see from your iptables rules that your INPUT chain's default policy is `DROP`.
If you are "stopping" iptables by simply flushing all the chains, that would leave you with a machine that accepts nothing.

Once the firewall is stopped, try this:

```
$ iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
```

This will truly remove any filtering.

Comment: here is the output of those commands

Comment: that worked! how would i make that the default on boot?